Two seemingly identical types behaving differently?
I was trying to create an IntersectProps utility type to find the type that has the intersection of the sets of properties, such that if
type A = {
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
    z?: string;
};
type B = {
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
    w?: string;
};

then the IntersectProps of the two would be:
{
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
}

I found a way to do this for two types in this question Typescript how to create type with common properties of two types?
using the type
type Common<A, B> = { [P in keyof A & keyof B]: A[P] | B[P]; }
However, this only works for finding the intersection of two types, requiring multiple nested applications of Common if there are more.
I know that doing keyof U where U is a union type produces the union of the keys of the set I'm looking for.
I.e., keyof (A | B) is the type 'x' | 'y'
Therefore, to produce the type I want, I can do:
type AisectpropsB = {
    [K in keyof (A | B)]: (A | B)[K];
};

Note that this does work - AisectpropsB is the type `
{
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
}

Now, I thought I would just be able to generalise this as follows:
type IntersectProps<U> = {
    [K in keyof U]: U[K];
};

such that IntersectProps<A | B> is equivalent to AisectpropsB. Then if I had more types to intersect I could easily do IntersectProps<A|B|C|D|E|...|Z>.
However, and here's my problem, for some reason, IntersectProps<A | B> is NOT equivalent to AisectpropsB.
IntersectProps<A | B> instead resolves to IntersectProps<A> | IntersectProps<B>, which is equivalent to A | B, which is clearly not the same as AisectpropsB.
(Edit: Thanks to HairyHandKerchief23 in the comments, it does work if you define IntersectProps as
type IntersectProps<U, T extends keyof U = keyof U> = {
    [K in T]: U[K];
};

but this still doesn't explain why my original definition fails, this again looks like it should be equivalent to my original IntersectProps definition)
How can this be?
I have a further point of confusion here also, as it appears that
A | B further reduces to
{
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
    z?: string;
    w?: string;
};

which is also not what I expected. I would have expected A & B to produce that result, but I expected that A | B would produce the following type, not allowing 'w' and 'z' to coexist:
{
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
    z?: string;
} | {
    x?: string;
    y?: string;
    w?: string;
} ;

What's going on here?

In the last code snippet, that union does allow w and z to coexist, in order for them to not coexist there has to be a property with a constant type in each of the union types. (e.g. x: true and x: false)

If you want to achieve this, i found a way to do it

Thanks. Any idea why that version works? It looks like it should be equivalent again to me. Also on the union allowing w and z to coexist, why does that work? I had been reading | as 'or' but that's clearly not the case. What would produce what I was expecting?

• TS uses the set theory definitions of union/intersection, but referring to the sets of values that match a type, and not the sets of property definitions. Types are contravariant in their keys, so unions/intersections flip. See this q. You are therefore using unconventional naming when referring to unions and intersections in TypeScript; please [edit] to either use different terminology, or be very clear what you're intersecting and uniting (e.g., IntersectProps).  Otherwise it's just a distraction from your question about how TS behaves.

• Once you do that, the answer is that type IsectProps<U> = { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } is a homomorphic mapped type as implemented in ms/TS#12447 and those distribute over unions, so IsectProps<A | B> will be equivalent to IsectProps<A> | IsectProps<B>. If you want to turn off distributivity over unions you need to make the mapped type non-homomorphic, by disrupting that in keyof sufficiently (like the alternative definition with K in T does). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what am I missing?

Thank you! Yes that does address most of it, although I would ask what specifically counts as 'disrupting' that in keyof sufficiently? How is that defined? Also, I get from your explanation why A | B produces what it does, do you know how would I produce what I was expecting?

• I don't know how it's "defined" unless I walk through the compiler implementation which I'm not inclined to do. Heuristically if you write in X where the definition of X isn't literally keyof Y then it's mostly disrupted. You can disrupt with in (PropertyKey & keyof Y) or in T where T is defined elsewhere, etc. Does that suffice?

• "do you know how would I produce what I was expecting"? You should ask just one question, not two. I suggest you remove that part and then look at the question/answer I linked above for why unions of types end up corresponding to intersections of properties but allowing things from other members.

Thanks, that suffices, happy to accept an answer :)

The definition
type IntersectProps<U> = {
    [K in keyof U]: U[K];
};

is a homomorphic mapped type as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#12447 (where it's called "isomorphic" instead). See What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?. The hallmark of such types is in keyof. When you have a homomorphic mapped type, it will, among other things, distribute its operation over unions, so that IntersectProps<X | Y | Z> is equivalent to IntersectProps<X> | IntersectProps<Y> | IntersectProps<Z>.
That's clearly not what you want to do, so you'd like to turn off the distributivity. There are various ways to do that, all of which involve "distrupting" the in keyof sufficiently, such as writing in ({} & keyof U) or in T where T is defined elsewhere.
Many of the ways that turn off the distributivity will also unfortunately turn off the part of homomorphic mapped types that you like: copying the optional-ness modifier from input to output properties. The one you mention
type IntersectProps<U, T extends keyof U = keyof U> = {
    [K in T]: U[K];
};

does a good job of turning off distributivity while keeping the optional-property-copying, because having T constrained to keyof U has that effect (mostly to allow the Pick<T, K> utility type to work as desired.
A lot of this stuff isn't particularly easy to find in the documentation (The TS team considers the GitHub issues part of their documentation, but that doesn't make it easy to find) so there's no simple place I can point to that defines exactly how to turn on and off different features of mapped types. Most of this is heuristic knowledge gained from using the language a lot.

"the TS team considers the GitHub issues part of their documentation" - really? Oh.

Yeah, I haven't found a comment by RyanCavanaugh/DanielRosenwasser saying this, but stuff like this comment by community members appears all over the place. It seems to be common knowledge that they gave up on the spec and said "github issues are where language features are documented" but I haven't found the official policy of that written... I think it probably is written somewhere, just not going to spend a long time looking.

Oh wow. Thank you. Yeah, no need to go looking further for an official statement if you don't have a link at hand. I'm going to share that regardless…

AisectpropsB is not the same as IntersectProps because AisectpropsB considers all properties from the union of A and B, while IntersectProps (used with intersection types) would only include common properties and their intersecting types.

AisectpropsB reflects the union of properties from both A and B, with the type being the union of the types of each property.

IntersectProps (where U is a type like A & B) reflects the properties common to A and B with their types from the intersection of those properties.


You can use the following instead:
type IntersectionOfTwo<T1, T2> = {
  [K in keyof (T1 | T2)]: (T1 | T2)[K];
};

type IntersectionOfThree<T1, T2, T3> =
    IntersectionOfTwo<IntersectionOfTwo<T1, T2>, T3>;

type IntersectionOfFour<T1, T2, T3, T4> = 
    IntersectionOfTwo<IntersectionOfThree<T1, T2, T3>, T4>;

// ...

type x = IntersectionOfTwo<A, B>;// { x?: string; y?: string; }
type y = IntersectionOfThree<A, B, { x?: string }>;  // { x?: string; }


This doesn't address the question as I was using IntersectProps with union types e.g. IntersectProps<A|B> not intersection types. jcalz' answer is correct
